# Backbone.js: access parent view from child view?

Tags: backbone.js, view, backgrid

In general, how to access parent view from a child view in Backbone?

Specifically, in Backgrid.js, is there a way to access parent row from a cell?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Pass `this` as an option to the child view on initialization step:

```
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function (options) {
    this.parent = options.parent;
  }
});

// somewhere in the parent view ...
new ChildView({parent:this});
```

Comment: How do you do it with a CompositeView and ItemView?

Comment: @hakunin in Marionette you can do it in the same way. Just use proper view e.g. `Marionette.ItemView` instead of `Backbone.View`

Comment: Not the same way - you don't construct the child view yourself in case of CollectionView, so you have to use childViewOptions or something instead. Anyway, I found even passing via triggerMethod didn't require any extra effort so I use that.

Comment: @hakunin sorry, but your question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Can we access the parent view models?

Answer (score -2):

```
// You can use this code instead

var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function (options) {
    this._configure(options); // Set all the options as local variables
    // This is used in the Backbone.View code on the latest version

  }
});
```

Comment: Don't see `_configure` anywhere in the Backbone source. I do see `_.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));` though. In this case, it would be used as follows: `_.extend(this, _.pick(options, ['parent']));`